# how do I findviewbyid of a view inside a tabhost from an activity thats inside the tabhost?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost

I'm trying to retrieve a view but it keeps returning null, how do I find it?

```
public class TripDailyItinerary extends Activity {
ViewGroup layout;
View v;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.html_content);  
TextView content = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.htmlContent);
layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.layout.trip_content);
v = (View) layout.findViewById(R.id.bg); //where the error is


JSONObject reservation;
int resNumber = ((MyApp) this.getApplication()).getResNum();
String dailyitinerary = "";

try {
reservation = ((MyApp) this.getApplication()).getJSON().getJSONObject("response").getJSONArray("reservations").getJSONObject(resNumber);
dailyitinerary = reservation.getString("dailyitinerary");
} catch (JSONException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
content.setText(Html.fromHtml(dailyitinerary));
}

}
```

I keep getting a NullPointerException at v = (view) .... etc.

Comment: You need to check your viewId correctly in your layout.Share the code and shorten the question description as it is even bigger then the actual question.

Comment: Alright, did so, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.layout.trip_content);
v = (View) layout.findViewById(R.id.bg); //where the error is
```

replace the above two lines with below

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
view view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.R.layout.trip_content,null);
TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bg);
```

also TextView can be replaced with your control either ImageView and any other.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.trip_layout);
LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trip_content,parent);
```

If you want to add TextView

`TextView content = (TextView)myView.findViewById(R.id.htmlContent);`

Because the `null` makes warning ..

`R.id.trip_layout` is the parent layout of your XML Layout .