# findViewById with TabHost Activities

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new in Android Coding so i hope someone can help me..
I found so. with a similiar problem [how do I findviewbyid of a view inside a tabhost from an activity thats inside the tabhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023058/how-do-i-findviewbyid-of-a-view-inside-a-tabhost-from-an-activity-thats-inside-t)
but the answer did not work for me...My App includes a main.xml and tab1.xml and tab2.xml
each one has an Activity class here the code :

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {  


/** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
Intent tab1, tab2;

@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  

    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);  


    TabSpec firstTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");  
    TabSpec secondTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid2");  

    tab1 = new Intent(this, tab1Activity.class);
    tab2 = new Intent(this, tab2Activity.class);

    firstTabSpec.setIndicator("TAB1").setContent(tab1);  
    secondTabSpec.setIndicator("Tab2").setContent(tab2);  

    tabHost.addTab(firstTabSpec);  
    tabHost.addTab(secondTabSpec);  

}
```

And here the Activity of the tabHost

```
  public class tab1Activity extends Activity
  {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.xml);

    EditText t = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.note);
    t.setText("Test"); // here it crashes!

}

 }
```

So my question how can i use findViewById global? Should i work with intents ?
Would be great if someone help me!! :-)

Comment: post the xml.xml in layout folder.

Comment: Do you even have layout named `xml.xml`? Because that's the layout you set in `setContentView()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check which layout you have set in the contentView. Could be the source of your problem.

```
 public class tab1Activity extends Activity
  {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.xml);　// <-------- your problem could be here

    EditText t = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.note);
    t.setText("Test"); // here it crashes!

}

 }
```